# Convert line from BASH to Python

Tags: python, bash

I have a line in a BASH script that looks like

```
 VAR="stuff=1"$'\n'"more_stuff=1"$'\n'"even_more_stuff='abc'"
```

I have two questions, what does

```
 "$'\n'
```

do?

and What would that line look like in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bash and zsh interprets $'\n' as a new line

```
VAR="stuff=1"$'\n'"more_stuff=1"$'\n'"even_more_stuff='abc'"
echo "$VAR"
```

output

```
stuff=1
more_stuff=1
even_more_stuff='abc'
```

in python

```
VAR = "stuff=1\nmore_stuff=1\neven_more_stuff='abc'"
print VAR
```

output

```
stuff=1
more_stuff=1
even_more_stuff='abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

bash don't interpret escape characters in string so if we write "\n" it prints it as it is. To avoid this we use $'\n' for line break.

*`In short its for line break in bash.`*

Answer (score 0):

[ANSI C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html):

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

So, `$'\n'` in bash is `"\n"` in Python.

In bash, you can stick strings together. `"a""b"` is the same as `"ab"`. In your line, to allow for different ways of quoting, you're sticking together five different strings; three are normal double-quoted ones, and in between there are two ANSI C quoted. In Python, you can do almost the same, but with a space in between: `"a" "b"` is equivalent to `"ab"`. The literal translation would thus be be

var = "stuff=1" "\n" "more_stuff=1" "\n" "even_more_stuff='abc'"

but you'd normally write it as

var = "stuff=1\nmore_stuff=1\neven_more_stuff='abc'"